# Save File on internal storage (document folder) permission denied

Tags: java, android, permissions, storage

I try to save files on my smartphone. Since I have no SD card installed I must save the data to my internal memory. The user must have easy access to the data later, so I want to store in an easily accessible location.
The following variant works without problems but is not easily accessible

```
File root = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(),"NAME");
        if(!root.exists()) root.mkdirs();
```

In this variant, I get the message that the access was denied.

```
Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
```

I also tried the following permissions:

```
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Does anyone know how to access these folders? The root directory would also be enough.

Thanks!

Comment: `Since I have no SD card installed I must save the data to my internal memory. `. Not true. You can as well use getExternalStorageDirectory() and variants getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(). Every device has external storage now adays.

Comment: `In this variant, I get the message that the access was denied.

Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS`. That is no variant. Show full code so we can see what you tried.

Comment: `also tried the following permissions:

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Not enough as creating a directory is considered WRITE.

Comment: `File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),"OBDTool");
            if(!root.exists()) root.mkdirs();`

Comment: no such file or directory. I dont get it! I have allready the Write permission as well

Comment: `if(!root.exists()) root.mkdirs(); ` Check the return value of mkdirs() and handle accordingly. `if(!root.exists()) if(!root.mkdirs()){Toast( ... could not create directory ...); return;}`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides asking for read and write permission in manifest for Android 6+ you should also add code to let the user confirm those permissions.

Google for runtime permissions.

You are #1258 with this problem this year.